# MapView not visible without hardware acceleration turned off

Tags: android, background, android-mapview, hardware-acceleration

I am using `Google Maps Android API v2` for showing a small `MapView`. However in order to implement a feature of my app I need hardware acceleration turned off for this view. Here is how I do that:

**onCreate:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.zoomControlsEnabled(false);
    options.rotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    options.scrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    options.tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
    options.zoomGesturesEnabled(false);

    MapView mv = new MapView(this, options);
    mv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));

    this.addView(mv);

    mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

The problem is that the map is not visible that way! One can see that the view should be there due to all views below that being pushed downwards, but it is not visible!

*Now here comes the weird part:*
If I add this line to my `onCreate` method, the map becomes visible

```
    mv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Why is this suddenly working? I want my background to be transparent, but adding `Color.TRANSPARENT` as a background is making the map disappear again :(

Comment: "However in order to implement a feature of my app I need hardware acceleration turned off for this view" -- I'd focus instead on this. What is this feature, and why do you think you need hardware acceleration turned off? Maps V2 makes heavy use of OpenGL, and so hardware acceleration is going to be pretty darn important for performance.

Comment: I want to add rounded corners to it by using *clipPath(...)* in *dispatchDraw(...)*. Unfortunately this is not possible using hardware acceleration :(

Comment: Oy. That being said, I'll be rather surprised if the Maps V2 team is focusing on having Maps V2 work well without hardware acceleration.

Comment: So you're saying that I should leave hardware acceleration turned on and forget about the round edges? :P

Comment: I am saying that disabling hardware acceleration is likely to be more error-prone than is leaving hardware acceleration alone.